# Why is my saved image file with Python Pillow smaller than the original?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, size

i was starting to get to used to Python and Pillow and just opened and saved a image file. Funky thing is, the new file is roughly half the mb as the original.
I read the doc for save (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) but didnt found a clue about that behaviour.

The properties of the file doesnt look different in resolution and depth.

Any clue why that happend?

here is my code

```
import PIL.Image

imageone = PIL.Image.open("/Users/Michael/Desktop/test1.png")
imageone.save("/Users/Michael/Desktop/test2.png")
```

[The file i got out of PIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJGmi.jpg)
The original file https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXqFH.jpg

[File details given by the OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYKlA.png)

I´ve found a nice online exif reader, which shows actually two differences. Here is a screenshot. Thanks to http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi

[Side by Side Image Information Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4lr5.png)

Comment: Isn't it possible append the ```.size``` parameter at save or call itself before to save definig the size?

Comment: Your output file is a JPG?

Comment: There may be many parameters that affect how PIL writes your png file. The one I spotted in the documentation was the compression. Perhaps your original had no compression and because PIL uses *some* compression it is possible this accounts for the difference.

Comment: The outputfile is a png, it supposed to be a png by the file path postfix. The way i understand the doc in that way.
It might be a default compression. Is there a way to check this out?